# How do I find out which application prevents the drive from going to sleep

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have 3 SATA HDDs in my server. The first one is a SSD system drive, and the other two (in JBOD) are being used to store some data (accessed via Samba). Most of the time when there are no requests, those two data drives can go to sleep. However only one of those two does.

I have already set the `noatime` flag in `fstab` for both drives and Im pretty sure that there's no cron job accessing this drive. I also set the spindown timeout to 10 minutes (`hdparm -S 128` command) for both.

Is there a way how do I determine which application still accesses the drive and preventing it from going to sleep?

I wouldn't normally care whether the drive is sleeping or not, but as this is a home server, setting those two drives asleep is worth saving some energy. The OS is Ubuntu Server 10.04.

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [powertop](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/).

Another thing to try is to check which processes have files open on the filesystem in question. See the tools "lsof" and "fuser".

Comment: Link is dead? This is the official GitHub repo: https://github.com/fenrus75/powertop

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard good things about powertop.

However, you could also look at **iotop** (found on newer distros). iotop also help you identify what programs are writing to disk.

(It's also generally useful to see how much io a given process is doing.)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As you are on linux, you can use the new `fatrace` utility, which logs every file access and tells you which process is responsible:

https://launchpad.net/fatrace

More information here:

http://www.piware.de/2012/02/fatrace-report-system-wide-file-access-events/

It makes use of the [linux fanotify API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) ([more details](http://lwn.net/Articles/360955/)) available since linux kernel 2.6.37.

`fatrace` isn't packaged by most distributions as of July 2014 (it entered debian testing recently, so should ship in 'jessie'), but is easy to install from source.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the drive handles this..
Doesnt hdparm edit the harddrives conf???

I used the exact same configuration to put my disks to sleep..
Movies/Music/Pictures worked great, a small 40gb disk for my OS and logs :D

i know that NFS keeps the disks alive, writing logs also.. basically any binary that needs or could stat a file on the underlying disks would keep them spinning

Take a look at what your storing on these disks.. other than static files and the applications which work refer to them..